# Multiple Ascending Panels in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

so here is my codes assuming that I have 4 panels in ascending order and 4 buttons each respectively here

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles maindishButton.Click

    panelDrink.Visible = False
    dessertPanel.Visible = False
    sidedishPanel.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drinksButton.Click

    panelDrink.Visible = True
    dessertPanel.Visible = False
    sidedishPanel.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dessertButton.Click
    panelDrink.Visible = False
    sidedishPanel.Visible = False
    dessertPanel.Visible = True

End Sub
Private Sub sidedishButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sidedishButton.Click
    sidedishPanel.Visible = True
    panelDrink.Visible = False
    dessertPanel.Visible = False
End Sub
```

problem is the 3rd and 4th panel always go black or empty when click :(

Comment: This isn't C#. This looks like VB

Comment: You know VB.NET has it's own tag, and C# is not VB.NET...

Comment: "black or empty" is very vague.  At least use View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline.  Provides a good way to see that one panel might be inside another panel so gets hidden as well when the outer panel gets hidden.  Consider to uplift your design a bit with UserControls.  If that doesn't help then use Task Manager, Processes tab and verify that your program isn't burning 100% core.  The kind of accident that happens when a Paint event handler does too much and causes yet another paint, anything that gets painted after it never gets a chance.